# Joomla Migration 1.5 => 2.5 : item-separator

Tags: migration, joomla2.5

I just migrated a joomla 1.5 site to 2.5
The last problem I have is related to item-separator :
Its a menu item that shows blog of categorie

In V1.5 I got :
[image]

Now in 2.5 I get :
[image]

The Item separator should separate the items - instead he's directly under the title of the item.

Is there any CSS solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the CSS code to seperate the articles in my template.  Might need to use some float tag to get it to float around the picture.

```
div.item-separator {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b10042;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, resolved it by using this in my stylesheet:

```
.item-separator {display:block; clear:both; height:20px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

finally the correct anwered.
I'm using jommla 2.5 and this ERROR is there!!
solved overwritting the core joomla in my .css file in the template.